# Video from file on computer not playing with <video> HTML5

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, video, html5-video

I have a mp4 file in my app's directories titled `hook.mp4`. It is located in the same file path as the `html` file that references it. The `html`file I am referencing the video from is an *Angular partial*. Unsure if that should be an issue.

***This is what my code looks like...***

**HTML...**

```
<video controls>
    <source src="./hook.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

[image]

Stupid drawings aside, it seems to me like I am following the instructions of many *Stack Overflow* answers about this as well as what they suggest at [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp). Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `./` in your `src` attribute?

Comment: @kaonashi Yes. That doesn't work either. I've also tried just a `/hook.mp4`. Still no dice...

Comment: What does your browsers net tab say, 404? If so have u got an html base path set that is causing issues? Is the video request url what you would expect it to be?

Comment: @danday74 The video player shows up, just not video.

Comment: Yes but what does net tab say? If u don't know what net tab is then google it, it's easy to access, need to know wot it says when it requests video file

Comment: @danday74 Will get back to you in ten minutes. AFK. I got .ogv files to work though. I think it is a browser compatibility thing...

Comment: @danday74 The net tab only says that it calls to the css stylesheet, nothing else. I can only get it to work with someone else's `.ogv` files, not my own. The following works `<source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv" type='video/ogg'>`, where as the following doesn't... `<source src="lunge.ogv" type='video/ogg'>`

Comment: @danday74 Figured it out! Apparently, because I am using Angular, I need to put the file it self in the same folder as the initial index.html folder with the angular file. I am not sure why, but I guess that is a thing with `<video>`. Don't need to do that for anything else (like `<audio>`). Bizarre.

Comment: Nice job  well done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that when dealing with `<video>` `HTML5` tags in angular, the path of the file you are attempting to load for your video needs to originate and the file in which you load angular `<script>` tag(your landing index page where you likely put your `ng-view` to display other partials).

I am not sure why, but that is what ultimately solved my problem.